# Jetty HTTP 2 Clients sharing same thread pool

Tags: jetty, http2

Using Jetty 9.4.7

We are creating 2 clients using this code:

```
    client = new HTTP2Client();
    client.setIdleTimeout(-1);//disable client session timeout
    client.setExecutor(httpThreadPool);
    client.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutMs);
    try {
      client.addBean(this.sslContextFactory);
      client.start();         
      FuturePromise<Session> sessionPromise = new FuturePromise<>();
      client.connect(sslContextFactory, new InetSocketAddress(this.host, this.port), new CustomSessionListener(clientInstanceName, this), sessionPromise);
      this.session = sessionPromise.get(this.connectionTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch(...
```

The httpThreadPool is common between the two clients. It is a ThreadPoolExecutor with core pool size 4 and max pool size 128.

The first client is created successfully. The second client fails with TimeoutException (regardless of the target servers, we even pointed them at the same server).

If we assign separate thread pools (or let the client construct its own default QueuedThreadPool) everything works fine.

Aside for an advice on the issue itself, is there any way to unwrap whatever exception is thrown when connecting the Http2 client? We tried overriding onFailure(Session,Throwable) in SessionListener, but it doesn't get there.

Thanks.

EDIT: Log excerpt on DEBUG: https://pastebin.com/MUKrw4JP

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging for the category `org.eclipse.jetty` and you should have a lot more information about what's going on. You can attach the logs here.

Comment: Attached logs. I'm afraid they don't help me too much. Perhaps you can nudge me in the correct direction :)

Comment: The logs do not match what you're doing in the code. There is no `TimeoutException`. The attempt to connect does not finish because the client is stopped before the server can complete the TLS handshake. The stream idle timeout is too small at only 100 ms. It is better if you post the whole code and whole logs. Try first with the configuration at its default values, and only when it works you can try changing it. I think you have only misconfigured the client, so should be an easy fix.

Comment: This is only the log for the org.eclipse.jetty pattern. The TimeoutException is java.concurrent and is thrown on FuturePromise.get. But I think this should be fairly easy to reproduce: just try to connect two clients sharing the same ThreadPoolExecutor, with the TP having 4 core threads or less. We increased that to 8 and it works. Since the max number of threads is 128, that should not matter normally. Also, is there a way to access the ACTUAL exception (i.e. not TimeoutException?). I mean, why did the client stop? Was it because of the stream timeout?

Comment: The log category does not matter, the `TimeoutException` must be in the logs but it's not, which means that you're not looking at the right (or complete) logs. If you have a reproducible test case, please attach it to an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues. The client stopped because your application stopped it.

Comment: We have a separate appender for each category - though I fail to see the relevance. Regardless of the allocated time, the setup always fails with the same exception. Surely the exact moment of the TimeoutException cannot be of any importance: it is exactly how many millis were set in the FuturePromise.get call. Also, the same setup works with 8 core threads but fails with 4. The code is as quoted in the issue. Sure, I'll take the time to prove it in a reproducible test case, if nothing else helps.

Comment: Please try Jetty 9.4.8. It is quite probable that you have vastly underconfigured the thread pool, and Jetty 9.4.8 will have better exception messages when this happens.